# Test if $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} $ = O(1)

Tags: asymptotics

I have to test if  $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}  =  O(1)$.

To show: $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}  \le c \cdot 1$

So my attempt was:

$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}  =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2\frac{1}{2^n} $ then split the sum to $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} $

With: $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} 
 = \frac{1}{1-0.5} = 2 $

we have $ 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n \le c \cdot 1$

as $2^n $ grows to infinity means that there is no $c$ that the inequality is always true, so $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} \ne  O(1)$.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me if I am on the right way or if this is all wrong.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 6):

It is false that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} \ge  \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \right),
$$
assuming that's what you meant. You can see that the first series on the right side diverges while the second converges to a positive constant.

To show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} = O(1)$ you can notice that, for $n \ge 16$, you have $n^2 \le 2^{n/2}$. Then, defining $c = \sum_{n=0}^{15} \frac{n^2}{2^n}$:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} =
c + \sum_{n=16}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} \le 
c + \sum_{n=16}^\infty \frac{2^{n/2}}{2^n} <
c + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{n} = c+ \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} = O(1).
$$

Answer (score 6):

The expression
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}
$$
is constant. Therefore there are two options:

1. The expression is not well-defined. This would happen, for example, if the series diverges.
2. The expression is well-defined, in which case it is $O(1)$ (since any constant is $O(1)$).

One fine point is that in computer science, we often only consider functions which are eventually positive. Therefore one reason for the expression to be not well-defined is if it the constant is non-positive.

In this particular case, it is easy to see that the series converges (in fact, it is equal to 6), and in particular, it is $O(1)$.